# Not getting forms to post data in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using function based views in Django rest framework. But when i open webpage in browse, I am not getting forms to post data.When i scroll down getting media type and content option not my model fields. In my model i have user_name, user_email fields but not showing there. Do i need to use class based views for that? Below is the screenshot.

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def user_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = User_Data.objects.all()
        serializer = User_Data_Serializers(data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.data
        serializer = User_Data_Serializers(data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using serializer?

Comment: @hspandher yes i am using serializers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible when using DRF functional views. You will need to switch to class based views or DRF's viewsets. The reason is because in order to render a form, DRF renderer needs to know which serializer is being used for the view from which it can pull out all the various fields. In CBV, its defined by using an attribute:

```
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
   serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Since there is no equivalent for doing that in functional views, I dont think it will be possible to achieve your requirement.

---

What you are trying to achieve is actually really simple in DRF viewsets:

```
# viewsets.py
class UserViewSet(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User_Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = User_Data_Serializers

# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, 'users')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The above 3 line viewset achieves the same effect as your functional view. Pretty cool I think!